# Knockout's HTML binding + SVG

Tags: javascript, firefox, knockout.js, svg

I'm using Knockout to render dynamic SVG's by passing strings into an SVG data-bound with the `html:` binding. In Chrome this works perfectly. In Firefox it will set up the DOM correctly (i.e. I can see that the child svg elements are present in firebug) but the graphic itself is not displayed.

I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4eTJL/1/ but interestingly, the Firefox behavior shows in both browsers in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<svg>` tag has no `innerHTML` property, that's why `ko html` binding doesn't work, but you can avoid this problem by putting all svg content inside `logo` variable, then bind it to a standard html tag.

https://jsfiddle.net/4eTJL/2/

```
<div data-bind="html: logo"></div>

var vm = {
    logo: '<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="center-block" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" data-bind="xml: logo"><rect ry="8" rx="8" id="svg_2" height="50" width="50" y="0" x="0" stroke-width="5" fill="#bfbfbf"></rect><text font-family="Graduate" textLength="40" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" text-anchor="middle" x="25" y="37" font-size="33" fill="crimson" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.25">NO</text></svg>'
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: I don't know why Chrome shows different result from local test to jsfiddle. I tried to play `DOCTYPE` both locally and on jsfiddle, but it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: That did it! I'm curious too though. It might have something to do with how knockout's html binding works in the presence of jQuery? the docs mention it does something different.